# unrecognized database format в приложении C# Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Добрый день, попросили создать простенькое приложение для учета техники, приложение я сделал, сперва создал в Access 2010 БД с таблицей и нужными полями, потом создал в visual studio проект Windows Form Application и подключил к форме БД. Скомпилировал, программа работает, можно добавлять/удалять записи и сохранят данные в таблицу. Проблема вылезла когда решил запустить приложения на другом компьютере. Выходит ошибка **Net framework unrecognized database format 'путь к базе.accdb'**

Проблема в том что я не разработчик и даже не знаю C#, меня попросили помочь, очень нужно человеку для учебы.
AccessDatabaseEngine я уже установлен.

Подскажите пожалуйста куда копать.

Comment: Скольки битная у Вас версия `Access`? и сколько бит `Access` на втором компьютере?

Comment: Постараюсь описать так чтобы не запутать, на компьютере где я делал приложение, MS Acсess не установлен вообще, а вот на компьютере где я тестирую приложение установление MS Access 2010 где собственно я и создавал саму БД.

Comment: Там где есть MS Access 2010 версия 64 разрядная

Answer (score 0):

Итак разобрался в проблеме для запуска приложения необходимо установить Office 2010 c MS Access (собственно в котором и была создаба БД, которая в последствии была вставлена в форму приложения). Проверял на Windows 7 и Windows 10, в обоих случаях после уставновки Office 2010 c MS Access приложение запускается без проблем.